# CFSpreadsheet Read - Wrong decimal symbol after updating to Windows 10

Tags: coldfusion, localization, windows-10, coldfusion-10

A few days ago I updated my windows from 8 to 10.  I reinstalled ColdFusion 10 and Apache (Xammp), and I installed all updates through the CF Administrator, including upd18. However, I am having a problem with the decimal symbol when I use `cfspreadsheet` and Excel.  The output is now different from my production server, and when I used window 8.

Here I have a print screen from one test I did using Excel with 4 different number masks. On the left is my localhost. On the right is the Production server.
[image: CFSpreadsheet results on localhost versus Production Server]

Additional observations: 
The Production Server is running ColdFusion 11. However, another PC with CF10 + Xampp + Windows 8 produces the same output as my Production server, which is different than result from my locahost.

Comment: Are the results above from reading the *exact same* Excel file? What formats are use for those cells in Excel?

Comment: is the same file, but i discovered the problem. My Windows is pt-BR, and windows server  is en-US.
a year ago we need to change JVM.config, we find the documentation that we did. Iccluding the following informatio to JVM.config the problem stoped.
 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US.

Comment: Yes, I edited a comment before you answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the problem. My Windows is pt-BR, and windows server  is en-US.
a year ago we need to change JVM.config to ColdFusion server works in en-US, we find the documentation that we did. Including the following information to JVM.config the problem stopped.

```
 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
```

Is possible edit this config in CFAdministrator
[image]

Comment: Whichever method you choose, making a backup of `jvm.config` first is always a good idea. Then if anything goes wrong, and CF does not start, just restore the "good" backup.

Comment: Perfect @leigh, if you do something wrong, The coldfusion service will not start. Backup is aways a good idea